# Given the vertices of a convex polytope, how can we construct its half-space representation?

Tags: convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, polytopes

Let us say I have the vertices of a polytope $V = \{v_1,\dots,v_k\} \subset \mathbb R^n$. Is it possible to write $V$ as intersection of half-spaces using the information from the vertices, i.e., can I write the polytope in the form $Ax \leq b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$?

The columns of $A$ are not necessarily the vertices of the given polytope. An example, consider a polytope in $\mathbb R^2_+$ with vertices $\{(0,1),(1,1),(2,0),(0,0)\}$. It can be observed that the corresponding half space representation is $Ax\le b$, where

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 \\\ -1 & 0\\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

and $b = (1,2,0,0 )^T$. Thank you.

Comment: Are the columns of $A$ supposed to be the vectors in $V$?  What is $m$?  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, there are algorithms for this: see e.g. Ziegler's book.

Comment: Ziegler has more than one book, but I'm sure Dan means the one "Lectures on polytopes", which does discuss going back and forth between $V$-representation and $H$-representation (i.e. vertex representation and hyperplane representation) of a polytope.  

Comment: I will try to get the book and see the relevant sections.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem you identify is called the *facet enumeration* problem in the literature: Given the vertices, find a description of the facets.
There has been quite a bit of work on this.  For $n$ points in $d$ dimensions,
$O(n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor})$ is achievable, and aymptotically worstcase optimal.
But this is a theoretical result.  The work of Avis & Fukuda, to which Igor refers,
is quite practical, achieving a complexity of $O(d^{O(1)} n M)$ where $M$ is the size
of the output description.  Here is one reference:

> D. Bremner, K. Fukuda, and A. Marzetta. 
>   "Primal-dual
>   methods for vertex and facet enumeration." 
>   *Discrete
>   Comput. Geom.*, 20(3):333 – 357, 1998.
>   ([Citeseer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.56.6514), which includes a PDF download link.)

If you are interested in software, permit me to also suggest [polymake](http://www.polymake.org/doku.php):

          
[image: polymake 24-cell]

Comment: polymake is a nice piece of software, once you get it installed, but that first step is highly nontrivial :(

Answer (score 4):

If you want software, there is [Komei Fukuda's cdd et al.](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/soft/soft.html)

Comment: I will check it and confirm. I believe it will work for me.

Comment: cdd worked for me. Many Thanks for your answer.