# Approximation of convex hull in high dimension

Tags: convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

What are efficient methods (polytime) to compute an approximation of the convex hull in high dimension (say, $30000$) for a given set of points?

**Edit:**
I am looking for an algorithm for getting t**he hyperplanes that define the convex hull**, **not** the extreme points that are the vertices of the convex hull.

Answer (score 5):

This recent paper

> Sartipizadeh, Hossein, and Tyrone L. Vincent. "Computing the Approximate Convex Hull in High Dimensions." [arXiv:1603.04422](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04422) (2016).

includes a summary of previous work on approximate convex hulls. The time complexity of their algorithm is independent of the dimension,
and quadratic in the number of points. 
"The proposed algorithm uses a greedy method to
attempt to find the best approximation to the convex hull
for a given number of vertices."

Comment: well the algorithm produce a subset of the points, which produces a approximate convex hull. But i am looking for an algorithm for getting the hyperplanes, which define the convex hull.

Comment: @test100: See the earlier MO question, "[Given the vertices of a convex polytope, How can we construct its Half-Space representation](http://mathoverflow.net/q/112426/6094)."