# How does one translate from convex hull to a set of facets (inequalities)?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Suppose I have defined a convex set as the convex hull of a set of points. (I know that all these points are "extremal points" of the convex set.) I know want to translate this description of the convex set into description in terms of a set of facets, or inequalities. Is there a general theory for how to do this?

In case the problem is hard in general, what if the convex set is "very symmetric", and the number of facets is similar to the number of vertices.

Comment: [Hermann Weyl’s take on the question](//books.google.com/books?id=TpbbVU4tA58C&pg=PA3) ([1935](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=38088)).

Comment: I believe you are asking to convert between the V-representation and the H-representation. There is a literature on this, under "facet enumeration problem." See this earlier MO question: [Given the vertices of a convex polytope, how can we construct its half-space representation?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/112441/6094).