# How to express a polytope by a matrix inequalty?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Consider a convex V-polytope generated by the origin and $n$ points $\mathbf{h}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{h}_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^r$. A Theorem in the area of convex geometry shows that each V-polytope is a H-polytope and vice versa.

My question is given $n$ points $\left\{\mathbf{h}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{h}_n \right\}$ how to express such a
V-polytope by the intersection of least half spaces (i.e., in a form of a matrix inequality).

---

One-dimensional case is trivial.

Comment: See this paper and references therein: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11843

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon Many thanks. I also notice that thie question is similar to the MO question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112426/given-the-vertices-of-a-convex-polytope-how-can-we-construct-its-half-space-rep?rq=1) asked before, so I vote for closing this one.